# EF Core commit transactions test

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm trying to figure out how to test commit failures for EF Core transaction resiliency. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency article describes scenario where if commit transaction fails, there may be a duplicate row left in the database. This looks likes a very low condition, but how do I test for it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to track every transaction to be sure your system is not duplicating rows? Or do you want to just write a single test to reproduce this condition?

Comment: Single test would do.

Comment: Any help? Would really appreciate some way of testing this.

Comment: Testing or just reproduce? What is the point about to check this?

Comment: I'd like to reproduce this behavior where failure in the transaction commit leaves extra records in the database. I have code where I would like to turn on 'retry on failure'. Code does insert into two tables and I'd like to make sure if works correctly if there is failure during committing of the transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I needed to make my own ExecuteInTransaction method and throw custom SqlException exception to force EF Core execute verifySucceeded method.